# How to get file url in loop from parse database

Tags: php, parse-platform, cakephp-2.3

```
$query = new ParseQuery("EVENT");
        $query->equalTo("EventUser", new ParseObject("_User",$this->Session->read('User.id')));
        $results = $query->find();

        $myEvent = array();
        if(isset($results)){
            for ($i = 0; $i < count($results); $i++) {
                $object = $results[$i];
                $file = $object->get('eventImage');
                $url = $file->getUrl();

                array_push($myEvent, array(
                    'id'=>$object->getObjectId(),
                    'EventName'=>$object->get('EventName'),
                    'eventImage'=>$url
                )); 
             }  
            $this->set(compact('myEvent')); 
        }
```

When I echo myEvent outside for loop then it is showing the error :

> Call to undefined method Parse\ParseFile::url()

Comment: Finally I got the answer So I am updating it. If there is no image in eventImage field then it will show error . We need to check $file if it exists then only get Url.
$file = $object->get('eventImage');
                                                                                      $url = $file ? $file->getUrl() : null ;